# How to prevent image control from being "selectable" / show selection border?

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

I have 2 images in a Gridview, and when I run my app the images have a border around them when I mouseover. (see behaviour ->)
[Behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tScMo.gif)

Can this be disabled, I've tried all the settings which seem related, such as:

```
                Image x:Name="image1" Height="67" Width="67" 
            Source="ms-appx:///Assets/logo67.png" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
            IsDoubleTapEnabled="False" 
            IsHoldingEnabled="False" 
            IsRightTapEnabled="False" 
            IsTapEnabled="False" 
            ManipulationMode="None"/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit the GridViewItem template, which have default value here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299127.aspx

Create a custom style and apply it using `ItemContainerStyle` property of GridView

Comment: Thanks @thang2410199  That seems harder than it should be. The Property I had to change.         ` <Style TargetType="GridViewItem" x:Name="GridViewItemContainerStyle">
            <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"></Setter>
        </Style>            'code' <Style TargetType="GridViewItem" x:Name="GridViewItemContainerStyle">
            <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"></Setter>
        </Style>`

Comment: Glad to help, did you get the style and behavior you desired ?